# How to fetch user's birthday from Facebook API in iOS using latest Facebook sdk?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

How to fetch user's birthday from Facebook API in iOS using latest Facebook sdk?

I have tried to fetch it

```
 {@"fields": @"id, name, link, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large), email, birthday"}
```

and have given permission

```
[login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile", @"email", @"user_friends",@"user_birthday"] handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error)
```

But not able the fetch birthday.

Answer (score 3):

You can't fetch users birthdate only yours you can get and you have to send app in review for approve in facebook developer after than if your app approve than you can set extra permissions but i don't think that users birthday you can get.

Answer (score 2):

Use this code.This may help you

```
(IBAction)btnfb:(id)sender

    {
      if (!FBSession.activeSession.isOpen)
            {
                NSArray *_fbPermissions =    @[@"email",@"publish_actions",@"public_profile",@"user_hometown",@"user_birthday",@"user_about_me",@"user_friends",@"user_photos",];

        [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:_fbPermissions allowLoginUI:YES completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,FBSessionState state, NSError *error)
         {
             if (error)
             {
                 UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:error.localizedDescription delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                 [alertView show];
             }
             else if(session.isOpen)
             {
                 [self btn_fb:sender];
             }


         }];


        return;
}
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:[NSDictionary 

dictionaryWithObject:@"cover,picture.type(large),id,name,first_name,last_name,gender,birthday,email,location,hometown,bio,photos" 

forKey:@"fields"] HTTPMethod:@"GET" 

completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError 

*error)

     {
         {
             if (!error)
             {
                 if ([result isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
                 {
                     NSLog(@"%@",result);

                 }
             }
         }
     }];
}
```

Comment: i think this is only give your birthday but other user's you can't get using this.

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 3x:**

*Hope this will help anybody*

```
//MARK: - sign in with facebook

let fbLoginManager : FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()

fbLoginManager.logIn(withReadPermissions: ["email","user_photos","user_birthday"], from: self) { (result, error) -> Void in

    if (error == nil) {
            let fbloginresult : FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult = result!
            print("fbloginresult######:\(fbloginresult)")

            if (result?.isCancelled)! {

                print(result ?? FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult())

            } else if(fbloginresult.grantedPermissions.contains("email")) {
                //show loader

                //print(user())
                //FETCH USER DATA

                if((FBSDKAccessToken.current()) != nil) {
                    FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large), email, birthday"]).start( completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) -> Void in
                        if (error == nil) {
                            //everything works print the user data
                            print(result ?? AnyObject.self)

                            if let jsondata = result as? [String: Any], let strEmail = jsondata["email"] as? String, let fb_id = jsondata["id"] as? String, let picture = jsondata["picture"] as? [String: Any], let data = picture["data"] as? [String: Any],let url = data["url"] as? String  {

                                // print(url)
                                print(strEmail)
                                print(fb_id)

                            }

                            //Loader hide

                        }

                    })
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the account in which you have registered your app. Don't try with other Facebook account.

It will give you a Birhtday.

Also check privacy settings of account.

Birthday may not be public. That can also be an issue.

Thanks

Comment: i Endorse your view

Answer (score 0):

Take in account that to get the birthday (and some other attributes like the user bio) the app has to be reviewed by Facebook. Otherwise, although the permissions  were given correctly to the user the Graph API call will not retrieve this attribute.