# Trying to get 'age_range' using Facebook Graph API in iOS (swift) but its missing 'max' value?

Tags: swift, facebook-graph-api

I want to get the `age_range` for the logged-in user. All fields are being returned successfully apart from the `age_range`.

This is my Facebook `GraphRequest` where I specify the requirements to fetch `age_range` field.

```
let graphRequest = GraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, email, name, picture.type(large), first_name, last_name, gender, age_range"], accessToken: AccessToken.current, httpMethod: .GET, apiVersion: .defaultVersion)
```

The json response only contains the `min` value and it's missing the **`max`** value.

```
"age_range" : {
    "min" : 21
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

21 is a valid age range with no max.

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/age-range/

[image]

Comment: righto! - in that case I think I need the DOB instead. thanks

Comment: I think that might not work out for you - unless you ask for advanced permissions (that the user can deny!); I take it you are logging in with the Facebook SDK?

Comment: Yes, I think if Birthday is private you cannot access it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32762170/how-to-fetch-users-birthday-from-facebook-api-in-ios-using-latest-facebook-sdk You might need to check if you have access, and then fallback to getting the user to tell you their DOB yourself. Alternatively don't use DOB (you very seldom need it, but some like APIs ilke MANGOPAY (why?) request it))

Comment: thanks for the info...I understand that DOB can be fetched with the pre-requisite that the user has granted permissions and FB has approved your app. I can get it to work while I'm testing it now.